# Lua NodeMCU net.udpsocket:listen - how to handle the possibility of the socket already being open?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I need to listen on an UDPsocket, but I don't know if the listener is already running.

I tried this approach to close any existing UDPsocket:

```
s=net.createUDPSocket()
s:on("receive",function(s,c) 

.... snip - define the handler ......

if (s~=nil) then 
    s:close()
    print("closing previous instance of UDP Server")
end

s:listen(7333)
print("UDP Server started")
```

If the socket is open, this fails with:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (udpserver.lua:104: not connected)
```

Then I tried this approach to only call listen if the socket didn't exist:

```
if (s==nil) then 
   s:listen(7333)
   print("starting UDP Server")
else
    print("Previous instance of UDP Server")
end
```

That doesn't work - s is never nil and I get "Previous instance of UDP Server" after a restart, but the socket is not actually listening.

Simply calling s:listen(7333) without any checking results in

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (udpserver.lua:105: address in use)
```

when the code is run and s:listen has previously been run.

I assume s=net.createUDPSocket() causes s to be non-nil, regardless of whether s:listen is ever called.  How can I detect whether listen has been called, or needs to be called?

EDIT - I'm new to Lua, and was thinking about the error "unprotected call"... So maybe there is a way to protect the call?  Some searching, and I learned about [pcall](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pcall). So I tried this approach:

```
lstatus, lret = pcall(s:listen,7333)     -- protected call to listen
if lstatus then 
   print("starting UDP Server")
else
    print("UDP Server - listen returned:",lret)
end
```

Surprisingly, I get this result:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (udpserver.lua:104: function arguments expected near ',')
```

So the Protected Call itself is unprotected.

Comment: Try `pcall(s.listen,s,7333)`. I don't think you can use the colon notation the way you were intending there.

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of comments or explanation on how pcall works (or doesn't work), I came up with this approach.

```
if not s_listening then 
  lstatus = s:listen(7333)   
  print("starting UDP Server - listening")
  s_listening = 1
else 
    print("UDP Server already listening")
end
```

I'd still be interested in knowing how I could query the status of a UDPsocket, or how pcall is actually supposed to work.